# mongodb query with group()?

Tags: mongodb

this is my collection structure :

```
coll{
id:...,   
fieldA:{
   fieldA1:[
       {
           ...
       }
   ], 
   fieldA2:[
       {
           text: "ciao",
       },
       {
           text: "hello",
       },   
   ] 
} 
}
```

i want to extract all `fieldA2` in my collection but if the `fieldA2` is in `two or more times` i want show only `one`.

i try this

```
Db.runCommand({distinct:’coll’,key:’fieldA.fieldA2.text’})
```

but nothing. this return all `filedA1` in the collection.

so i try

```
db.coll.group( {

               key: { 'fieldA.fieldA2.text': 1 },

               cond: { } },

               reduce: function ( curr, result ) { },

               initial: { }

            } )
```

but this return an empty array...

How i can do this and see the execution time?? thank u very match...

Comment: `fieldA` only shows `fieldA1` and 3 dots for its contents however in your group you are showing that you wish to group on a sub field of `text` within that field. What is the true structure of `fieldA1`?

Comment: Could you add desired output for exemplary input?

Comment: Sammaye: sorry.. i wish to group on fieldA2.text

Comment: Grzegorz: i want a list like this: ciao, hello, ... , ..., and all of this only one times. and then the query execution time

Comment: I believe that with the aggregation framework you might be able to do something like: `db.col.aggregate({$project: {"fieldA.fieldA2": 1}}, {$unwind: "$fieldA.fieldA2"}, {$group: {_id: "$fieldA.fieldA2.text"}});` it is untested though, I just put this together with memory atm

Comment: thanks but i have a problem. i have mongodb 2.0.4 and no support aggregate function and i can't uptade version because no depends to me..is there another way? thank u very match

Comment: Poop, the only way is through MR then :( Here I will put a MR draft up

Comment: hi, Sammaye. i uptade my mongodb and i try the follow commads: db.aggregate({$project: {"fieldA.fieldA2": 1}}, {$unwind: "$fieldA.fieldA2"}, {$group: {_id: "$fieldA.fieldA2.text"}}) but return more result then i expected but i don't  understand why. have u any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are running 2.0.4 (I recommend upgrading), you must run this through MR (I think, maybe there is a better way). Something like:

```
map = function(){
    for(i in this.fieldA.fieldA2){
        emit(this.fieldA.fieldA2[i].text, 1); 
        // emit per text value so that this will group unique text values
    }
}

reduce = function(values){
    // Now lets just do a simple count of how many times that text value was seen
    var count = 0;

    for (index in values) {
        count += values[index];
    }

    return count;
}
```

Will then give you a collection of documents whereby `_id` is the unique `text` value from `fieldA2` and the `value` field is of the amount of times is appeared i the collection.

Again this is a draft and is not tested.

Comment: thank for the answer.. i try your code but the follow error appears: map reduce failed:{
 "assertion" : "too much data for in memory map/reduce",
 "assertionCode" : 13604,
 "errmsg" : "db assertion failure",
 "ok" : 0
}

Comment: @alessio1985 That sucks, what about stennies answer? I know you have tried distinct before but I am sure that it should work if you try his example

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer is simpler than a Map/Reduce .. if you just want distinct values plus execution time, the following should work:

```
var startTime = new Date()
var values    = db.coll.distinct('fieldA.fieldA2.text');
var endTime   = new Date();

print("Took " + (endTime - startTime) + " ms");
```

That would result in a `values` array with a list of distinct fieldA.fieldA2.text values:

```
[ "ciao", "hello", "yo", "sayonara" ]
```

And a reported execution time:

```
Took 2 ms
```